# How to show graph of path between two refs in Git?

Tags: git

I'm using Git v2.6.1. I run the following command on two branches:

```
$ git log --drecorate --oneline --graph origin/release/6.0.0.10...origin/master --ancestry-path
```

The branch `release/6.0.0.10` was created off of `master`. However, the resulting graph does not show their merge base. They are not "connected" in the resulting view:

```
*   c62ea9b (origin/release/6.0.0.10)
|\
| * 43922fe
|/
* 6bb6187
* ff01d1e
* 3e949a9
* af6a5a8
* 6adff8d
* 4896edc
* bbebbf1
* 54c12e7
* 0b198c5 (origin/master)
* 33b1f9d
* 0e6c2a0
* 86371fe
* 3e341f4
* 3bbb8f4
* 05c3987
* 6688d10
* 2d6c270
* 18c36f3
```

**Note** that the merge base is *not* the tip of `origin/master`, yet it displays it that way. I expect to see one more vertical line, probably at the bottom, connecting the 2 refs together which would indicate their merge base. How can I change my invocation of the `log` command shown above to get the results I'm looking for?

Comment: Use just two dots instead of three? (or I'd rather just use `origin/release/6.0.0.10 ^origin/master`).

Comment: Two dots will not show the commits on the left operand, which is not what I want. Three dots shows commits that are reachable by either ref.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The three-dot syntax selects revisions that are reachable from either endpoint, *excluding* commits reachable from *both* endpoints.  That is, it throws away the merge-base and any earlier points.  Clearly you'll need to include the merge base to get the graph line drawn.

Two obvious options are:

- Back up one step from the merge-base.  This can't be done directly within the three-dot syntax; you'd have to find the actual merge-base commit.<sup>1</sup>  Since `A...B` "means"<sup>2</sup> `A B --not $(git merge-base A B)` you could do:

  ```
  base=$(git merge-base A B)
  git log A B --not ${base}^
  ```

  to get that effect.
- Use the `--boundary` option to `git rev-list`<sup>3</sup> to force it to include the boundary commits it normally excludes, which in this case will include the merge-base.

I'm not entirely sure how `--boundary` will interact with `--ancestry-path`, in this case (testing on the git repo itself gave me *two* boundary commits for the pieces of the DAG I tried).  It works fine with the `--simplify-by-decoration` option I used on a different repo, though.

---

<sup>1</sup>Or one of several, if there are multiple merge-bases (in such cases you might want to include all of them, but presumably here you can be sure there's just the one).

<sup>2</sup>More precisely, `A B ^$(git merge-base A B)`, or `A B --not $(git merge-base A B) --not`.  The extra `--not`, or using the prefix `^`, don't matter in this case, since there are no more revision names for `--not` to invert.

<sup>3</sup>log, rev-list, all pretty much the same command. :-)  You can get the graph out of `git rev-list` for instance.